# How can I concatenate multiple user inputs in JS?

Tags: javascript, concatenation, getelementbyid

I am just starting out but I am stuck in what many will likely find to be a simple problem. I am trying to have multiple inputs concatenate after a button is pressed at the end.

Here is the code I tried but only "fname" shows up after I click the button instead of the value that was input into the space. What am I missing?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>

  <p> Please enter your First Name: <input type="text" id="fname"></p>
  <p> Please enter your Last Name: <input type="text" id="lname"></p>
  <p> Please enter your User ID: <input type="text" id="uid"></p>
  <p> Please enter your date of birth: <input type="date" id="bday"></p>

  <button onclick="getEls()">Click Here<br>
        When Done</button>

  <script>
    function getEls() {
      document.getElementById("answer");
      answer.innerHTML = (Hello + "fname" + " " + "lname" + your user id is " uid" + and your birthday is + "bday".);
    }
  </script>

  <p id=answer>
    <p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should use string interpolation for this, your quotations seem to be breaking your string. Try something like `answer.innerHTML = \`Hello ${fname} ${lname} your user id is ${uid} and your birthday is ${bday}\``. See more about string interpolation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: First issue is that you have your `"` mixed up - you need `"` around the *literal string* - ie the static text or non-variable part, eg `"Hello " + fname + "."`

Comment: Second is that the global variable `fname` refers to the input with id=fname, not the value itself, so you need `"Hello " + fname.value + "."` - having said that, don't use the global variable, instead use `document.getElementById("fname").value`

Comment: Also note that you should assign `document.getElementById("answer");` to a variable, otherwise it's doing nothing for you

Comment: When you're having trouble with JavaScript, always look at the console, in the browser's developer tools; this would have pointed out the error `missing ) in parenthetical` and given you a place to start tracking down your error(s).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand well your question but is that what you want?

```js
function getEls() {
      var answer = document.getElementById("answer");
      var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
      var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
      var uid = document.getElementById("uid").value;
      var bday = document.getElementById("bday").value;
      answer.innerHTML = ("Hello " + fname + " " + lname + " your user id is " + uid + " and your birthday is " + bday + ".");
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>

  <p> 
    Please enter your First Name: 
    <input type="text" id="fname">   
  </p>
  
  <p> 
    Please enter your Last Name: 
    <input type="text" id="lname"> 
  </p>
  
  <p> 
    Please enter your User ID: 
    <input type="text" id="uid">
  </p>
  
  <p> 
    Please enter your date of birth: 
    <input type="date" id="bday">
  </p>

  <button onclick="getEls()">
    Click Here<br>
    When Done
  </button>

  <p id=answer>
  <p>

</body>

</html>
```

If you have any questions please tell me in the comment

Comment: Sterling and freedomn-m, thank you for your feedback, I truly appreciate it! amel and especially @DavidThomas, thank you for correcting my code and the explanations. The explanation gave me the reasons behind why it was not working and helped me understand, which is the most important part of this. Also, thank you David for taking the time to go the extra step to teach me how to clean it up even more!

Answer (score 1):

Your errors were a combination of typos (which would be a valid close reason), and a misunderstanding of how to use HTML `<input>` elements, and their values, in a String.

First, we'll look at the mistakes:

```
function getEls() {
  // here, you retrieve an element correctly but don't
  // assign it to a variable, and you do nothing with it;
  // this is valid JavaScript, and not necessarily an error,
  // but it's entirely pointless:
  document.getElementById("answer");

  // the reason that this works is the legacy of a terrible
  // decision by Microsoft - years ago - to make any element
  // with an id an automatic global variable, with the variable-
  // name being the (unique) id of that element. This is
  // a common implementation, but not listed in the spec so
  // it may change in future; don't rely on the behaviour (and
  // ideally don't use global variables):
  answer.innerHTML = 
    // here you have hard-coded String components to which
    // you want to interpolate/concatenate your supplied
    // variables; unfortunately (for reasons unknown) you chose
    // to leave the String unquoted (so, in JavaScript, these
    // become undeclared variables), and you've quoted the
    // variable names (and a lone white-space):
    (Hello + "fname" + " " + "lname" + your user id is " uid" + and your birthday is + "bday".);
    // Also, you seem to have a '+' operator missing, which
    // contributes to the 'missing ) in parenthetical' error.
}
```

To correct this:

```html
<p>Please enter your First Name: <input type="text" id="fname"></p>
<p>Please enter your Last Name: <input type="text" id="lname"></p>
<p>Please enter your User ID: <input type="text" id="uid"></p>
<p>Please enter your date of birth: <input type="date" id="bday"></p>

<button onclick="getEls()">Click Here<br>
      When Done</button>

<script>
  function getEls() {
    let answer = document.getElementById("answer"),
      fname = document.getElementById('fname'),
      uid = document.getElementById('uid'),
      bday = document.getElementById('bday');

    answer.innerHTML = ("Hello" + fname.value + " " + lname.value + "your user id is " + uid.value + " and your birthday is " + bday.value + ". ");
  }
</script>

<p id=answer></p>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/q0w1Ln8c/).

Now, while that works, we're going to refine it towards code that's more DRY (don't repeat yourself), and also towards unobtrusive JavaScript, which moves the event-handling out of the HTML:

```js
// using a simple named function, using Arrow syntax, to retrieve an element
// via its assigned 'id' attribute-value (this is optional, but personally I
// don't like typing 'document.getElementById(...)' more than once):
const dGEBI = (id) => document.getElementById(id),
            // your function, declared as a constant (on the assumption you're
      // unlikely to redefine the function through the lifetime of your
      // page):
            getEls = function () {
        // we retrieve the various elements, and assign them to
        // variables:
                let answer = dGEBI('answer'),
                // we retrieve the <input> elements, and cache their values:
                fname = dGEBI('fname').value,
            lname = dGEBI('lname').value,
            uid = dGEBI('uid').value,
            bday = dGEBI('bday').value;
        
        // here we use a template-literal to construct the String; this is
        // delimited by backticks; and we can directly interpolate JavaScript
        // variables or the results of JavaScript expressions into the String,
        // by wrapping them with curly-braces ('{...}') and prefixing with a '$'
        // character:'
        answer.innerHTML = `Hello ${fname} ${lname}, your user id is: ${uid}, and your birthday is: ${bday}. `
      }

// here we use document.querySelector() to retrieve the first (if any) element matching
// the supplied CSS selector; and then use EventTarget.addEventListener() to bind
// the getEls() function (note the deliberate lack of parentheses) as the event-handler
// for the 'click' event:
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', getEls);
```

```html
<p>Please enter your First Name: <input type="text" id="fname"></p>
<p>Please enter your Last Name: <input type="text" id="lname"></p>
<p>Please enter your User ID: <input type="text" id="uid"></p>
<p>Please enter your date of birth: <input type="date" id="bday"></p>

<button>Click Here<br>When Done</button>

<p id=answer></p>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/q0w1Ln8c/4/).

Next, We'll take a look at your HTML; and use `<label>` elements:

```js
const dGEBI = (id) => document.getElementById(id),
  getEls = function() {
    let answer = dGEBI('answer'),
      fname = dGEBI('fname').value,
      lname = dGEBI('lname').value,
      uid = dGEBI('uid').value,
      bday = dGEBI('bday').value;

    answer.innerHTML = `Hello ${fname} ${lname}, your user id is: ${uid}, and your birthday is: ${bday}. `
  }

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', getEls);
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

label:last-of-type {
  display: revert;
}
```

```html
<!-- Here, we've replaced the <p> elements with <label> elements; this
     allows the user to click the text of the <label> to focus the
     associated <input> element: -->
<label>Please enter your First Name: <input type="text" id="fname"></label>
<label>Please enter your Last Name: <input type="text" id="lname"></label>
<label>Please enter your User ID: <input type="text" id="uid"></label>

<!-- I've taken a different approach here, and used the 'for' attribute to
     associate the <input> and <label>; for this approach the 'for' attribute
     must contain the exact 'id' attribute-value of the relevant <input>: -->
<label for="bday">Please enter your date of birth: </label> <input type="date" id="bday">

<button>Click Here<br>When Done</button>

<p id=answer></p>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/q0w1Ln8c/3/).

References:

HTML:

- [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input).
- [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).
  JavaScript:
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement).
- [`HTMLLabelElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLLabelElement).
- [Template-literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).